# Optimising pygame

Tags: python, optimization, pygame

For my project in AH Computing I'm recreating my version of Nidhogg. Everything runs smoothly until the blood starts spraying. Im not too sure how i can make the code more efficient as i am still fairly new to python.

This is the class for the the spraying blood:

```
class bloodmaker():
def __init__(self,xv,yv,colour,x,y):
    self.gravity = 2
    self.air_resistance = 0.25
    self.xv = xv
    self.yv = yv
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.pastx = 0
    self.pasty = 0
    self.colour = colour
def move(self):
    if self.y < 400:
        self.pastx = self.x
        self.pasty = self.y
        #so that it doesnt curve backwards
        if self.xv > 0:
            self.xv -= self.air_resistance
        self.yv += self.gravity
        
        self.x += self.xv
        self.y += self.yv
        #so that the drawn line doesnt go over the edge
        if self.y > 400:
            self.y = 400
    
        if self.colour is "o":
            py.draw.line(screen, (255, 165, 0), (self.pastx-backgroundx, self.pasty), (self.x-backgroundx, self.y),5)
        else:
            py.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 0), (self.pastx-backgroundx, self.pasty), (self.x-backgroundx, self.y),5)
    else:
        global bloodgrid
        try:
            #the bloodgrid are squares 5 pixels wide, covering the bottom section, so we we divide by 5 to find where to put the blood
            bloodgrid[int(self.x/5)].insert(0,self.colour)
        except:
            pass
        #deleting this object as it is no longer required
        return True
```

[Here is an image of the blood spraying][1]
(excuse the incomplete sprite)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXiAa.png

Underneath there is a floor of blood that works using an array of stacks, which is added above code when it the blood reaches the floor.

```
bloodgrid = [[] for x in range(512)]
```

Here is the code for destroying the flying blood object and blitzing the blood floor to the screen.

```
def blood():
    for i in range(len(bloodarray)):
        killyourself = bloodarray[i].move()
        if killyourself is True:
            kill.append(i)
            #appends to a kill list as if i popped here the list would get shorter while the for loop stays the same giving an out of index error
    for i in range(len(kill)):
        bloodarray.pop(kill[0]-i)
        kill.pop(0)

    #printing the entire bloodgrid
        
    for i in range(512):
        for ii in range(len(bloodgrid[i])):
            try:
                if bloodgrid[i][ii] is "o":
                    py.draw.rect(screen, (255, 165, 0), ((i*5)-backgroundx, ii*5+400, 5, 5))
                else:
                    py.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 0), ((i*5)-backgroundx, ii*5+400, 5, 5))
            except:
                pass
```

I don't think it is possible to only update parts of the screen as the camera moves about and the blood on the floor moves too.

As more blood accumulates on the floor the game framerate starts to drop and it gets especially choppy when the blood sprays. Is there any ways I could make this more efficient? I don't want to hand in a choppy game but I really like how the blood looks. Thanks.

Comment: Your indentation is clearly wrong; please [edit] to fix it. On the desktop version of this site, you can get code marked up for you by pasting your code, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: I think .insert and .pop(0) are causing problems. Try implementing your code so that data is only added to or removed from the back of the list.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points that are hopefully helpful.

1. (This isn't directly related to speeding up your code, but...)  Try to get away from using global variables.  Just pass them into your functions.  Several of the ones you posted are difficult to figure out because you are accessing variables that are outside the scope of the function.
2. First reason things are bogging down here:  You are using `insert()` to insert new elements at the start of a list, and you are doing that inside of a loop where you call the `move()` function.  Inserting anywhere into a list (except the end) is horribly slow for reasons beyond the scope of this post.  You should consider putting a `deque` from `collections` in there, which can be inserted front or back efficiently.  If that is daunting, you could also "do a little math" and insert at the *end* of your list and draw it backwards by counting down from the last element, which is also efficient.
3. Also in the same notion, as mentioned in the comments, `pop`ing things out of the middle of lists or arrays is also horribly slow.  Figure out a different way or look at a different data structure.  It is tough to give advice on this point because `bloodarray` is not defined in your code.

Basically:  things are bogging down because you are choosing the wrong data structures.  tweak a couple of them and you'll get better results.

Comment: Thanks you so much i'll try and change that the insert and pop. I didn't realise the structures could affect the speed so much. bloodarray is an array of instances of the bloodmaker class.